# How to make table grow upward when dynamically adding rows?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to grow a table upward from a fixed position, so that if for example the first table row is at 100px, the next one would be at 110px (grows upward instead of the default downward). How could I achieve this effect if I am dynamically adding table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute positioning and instead of setting the offset with top use bottom. With this property you can ensure the position of the bottom edge of your div - any change in size will force the div to expand upwards.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and you are wanting to insert new rows into the table, but above the existing rows as opposed to below. This would be a `prepend` as opposed to an `append`, and you have a couple of nice `jQuery` options to do this:

[insertBefore](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/insertBefore):

```
$('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>').insertBefore('table > tbody > tr:first');
```

[before](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/before#content):

```
$('table > tbody > tr:first').before('<tr><td>Stuff</td></tr>');
```

[prependTo](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prependTo#selector):

```
$("<tr><td>prependTo</td></tr>").prependTo("table > tbody");
```

Comment: This would still cause the table to grow downwards.

Comment: @DerekPollard Yes that is what I was confused about. Does the OP want the table absolutely positioned to the bottom of a block element with space above, or does the OP want the appended rows to appear above those that already exist on the table.